# ASP Retrieving a trigger-populated field value - worked with earlier version of Oracle

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, oracle11g, oracle8i

The below sample ASP classic code that I have modified so it can be run via `cscript` or `wscript`, communicating with Oracle 8i and using Oracle ODBC Driver 8.01.07.00 running on Windows 2000, returns a valid `shipper_id`. This primary key field is populated via a `before insert or update` trigger (I can include it if necessary, but I have confirmed it works).

However, with Oracle 11, Oracle ODBC driver 11.02.00.03, and Windows Server 2012, only a blank value is returned - why?

Any help that can be provided would be appreciated.  Note that I would rather not have to switch to OO4O or use the Oracle Provider for OLE DB unless there is no other option.

```
Dim strCnxn, cnxn, rs
strCnxn = "DSN=OUR_DSN;uid=OUR_UID;pwd=OUR_PWD"

Set cnxn = Wscript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnxn.Open strCnxn
Set rs = Wscript.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SHIPPER", cnxn, 1, 3, &H0002 'adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
rs.AddNew
rs("CARRIER_ID") = "13263"
rs("NAME") = "test-shipper"
rs.Update

Wscript.Echo("Shipper ID: " & rs("SHIPPER_ID"))
Wscript.Echo("Carrier ID: " & rs("CARRIER_ID"))
Wscript.Echo("Name: " & rs("NAME"))

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnxn = Nothing
```